# How to make a spectrum With AVplayer？

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

Here’s my problem , I want make a dynamic sound spectrumView. and there I found a demo can do it simply by AVAudioPlayer.which means it works on local audio. the code is like:

```
SpectrumView * spectrumView2 = [[SpectrumView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 120, 80)];
spectrumView2.center = self.view.center;
__weak SpectrumView * weakSpectrum2 = spectrumView2;

spectrumView2.itemLevelCallback = ^() {

    [self.avAudioPlayer updateMeters];

    float power= [self.avAudioPlayer averagePowerForChannel:0];
    weakSpectrum2.level = power;
};

[self.view addSubview:spectrumView2];
```

but i use AVPlayer to play internet audio, so i can't use `updateMeters` and `averagePowerForChannel` Method. So is there any way i can use these two method by use AVPlayer ?(Swift demo is also ok)